# impacting Strings with pointers

Tags: c, crash, scanf

The code which does not work. In function `main` after initializing variables by the user, it goes to `if` part and after that crash happens. This program's goal is to impact the repetitive characters in the string. So I decided to have a pointer in a function `f1` and the pointer should point to `0th` char of the array `kar[]`
then compare the `0th char` to `1st char` but the program crashes exactly after the last `scanf("%s",kar[1000]).`
where is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
char f1(char* p)
{
    int i=0,c=1;
    while(*(p+i))
    {
        if(*p==*(++p))
        {
            c+=1;
            p++;
            i++;
            continue;           
        }
        else
        {
            if(c>1)
            {
                printf("%c%d",*p,c);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c",*p);
            }
        }
    i++;
    }
}



int main()
{
    int n,i,m;
    char kar[1000];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=(2*n);++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&m);
        scanf("%s",kar[1000]);
        if(m==1)
        {
            f1(kar);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: A couple of hints though: What do the `scanf` function expect for kind of arguments? How do you access a single element in an array? Uninitialized local variables including arrays like `kar`) are *uninitialized* with *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) values. And listen to your compiler, it should have shouted at you for that program.

Comment: And also [how to write readable code](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/programming-style-readability.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This only pertains to a _reasonable compiler_, not necessarily every one possible. : ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
      scanf("%s",kar[1000]);
```

should trigger a compiler warning, as you pass a `char` where a `char*` is expected. You pass the 1001st element of `kar` (which is out of `kar`'s bounds, BTW). In C array indices start with 0 for the 1st element.

To scan into `kar`, just pass *the address of `kar`'s 1st* element.

```
      scanf("%s", &kar[0]);
```

As arrays get decayed to the address of their 1st element when being passed to a function the following statement is equivalent

```
      scanf("%s", kar);
```

Please note that the above two statements very well allow the user to enter more characters then `kar` can hold and with this make `scanf()` overflow `kar`, that is write beyond it bounds, invoking undefined behaviour, which might crash your program or whatever ...

To avoid this tell `scanf()` the maximum to scan by doing:

```
      scanf("%999s", kar);
```

The maximum for `char`s a strings can hold in C is always one less then defined as C strings need one more `char` to have their end marked by a `'\0'`terminator.